# jndi database connection with jpa and eclipselink

Tags: java, tomcat, jpa, jndi, eclipselink

I try to setup a database connection in java with JNDI in combination with eclipseLink/JPA on Tomcat 5.5. I already configured the JNDI resource in web.xml and context.xml.

The db connection works with JNDI without using JPA and eclipseLink.
After configuring the persistence.xml for eclipseLink, I got the following exception.

I don't know how to configure the persistence.xml correctly to use JNDI datasource for the db connection.

The exception

```
WicketMessage: Method onFormSubmitted of interface      
org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.IFormSubmitListener targeted at component     
[MarkupContainer [Component id = loginForm]] threw an exception


Root cause:

javax.naming.NamingException: This context must be accessed throught a java: URL
at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.parseName(SelectorContext.java:686)
at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:121)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:396)
at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.JNDIConnector.connect(JNDIConnector.java:110)
at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.JNDIConnector.connect(JNDIConnector.java:94)
at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DatasourceLogin.connectToDatasource(DatasourceLogin.java:16    2)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.loginAndDetectDatasource(Datab    aseSessionImpl.java:579)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.login(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:228)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:380)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.getServerSession(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:157)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:214)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:202)
at de.company.myDs.controller.AbstractCrudController.getEntityManager(Unknown Source)
at de.company.myDs.controller.UserController.loadUserByName(Unknown Source)
at de.company.myDs.controller.LoginController.validateUserLogin(Unknown Source)
at de.company.myDs.pages.LoginPage$1.onSubmit(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.delegateSubmit(Form.java:1534)
at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.process(Form.java:934)
at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.onFormSubmitted(Form.java:896)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.invoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:182)
at org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.listener.ListenerInterfaceRequestTarget.processEvents(ListenerInterfaceRequestTarget.java:73)
at org.apache.wicket.request.AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.processEvents(AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.java:92)
at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.processEventsAndRespond(RequestCycle.java:1250)
at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.step(RequestCycle.java:1329)
at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.steps(RequestCycle.java:1428)
at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.request(RequestCycle.java:545)
at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doGet(WicketFilter.java:479)
at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:312)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:172)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:174)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:873)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:665)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:528)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:81)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:689)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:637)

Complete stack:

org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: Method onFormSubmitted of interface org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.IFormSubmitListener targeted at component [MarkupContainer [Component id = loginForm]] threw an exception
at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.invoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:193)
at org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.listener.ListenerInterfaceRequestTarget.processEvents(ListenerInterfaceRequestTarget.java:73)
at org.apache.wicket.request.AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.processEvents(AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.java:92)
at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.processEventsAndRespond(RequestCycle.java:1250)
at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.step(RequestCycle.java:1329)
at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.steps(RequestCycle.java:1428)
at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.request(RequestCycle.java:545)
at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doGet(WicketFilter.java:479)

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.invoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:182)
at org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.listener.ListenerInterfaceRequestTarget.processEvents(ListenerInterfaceRequestTarget.java:73)
at org.apache.wicket.request.AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.processEvents(AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.java:92)
at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.processEventsAndRespond(RequestCycle.java:1250)
at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.step(RequestCycle.java:1329)
at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.steps(RequestCycle.java:1428)
at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.request(RequestCycle.java:545)
at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doGet(WicketFilter.java:479)

javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-7060] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.1.0.v20100614-r7608): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: Cannot acquire data source [java:comp/env/jdbc/myDs].
Internal Exception: javax.naming.NamingException: This context must be accessed throught a java: URL
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:408)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.getServerSession(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:157)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:214)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:202)
at de.company.myDs.controller.AbstractCrudController.getEntityManager(Unknown Source)
at de.company.myDs.controller.UserController.loadUserByName(Unknown Source)
at de.company.myDs.controller.LoginController.validateUserLogin(Unknown Source)
at de.company.myDs.pages.LoginPage$1.onSubmit(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.delegateSubmit(Form.java:1534)
at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.process(Form.java:934)
at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.onFormSubmitted(Form.java:896)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.invoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:182)
at org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.listener.ListenerInterfaceRequestTarget.processEvents(ListenerInterfaceRequestTarget.java:73)
at org.apache.wicket.request.AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.processEvents(AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.java:92)
at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.processEventsAndRespond(RequestCycle.java:1250)
at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.step(RequestCycle.java:1329)
at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.steps(RequestCycle.java:1428)
at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.request(RequestCycle.java:545)
at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doGet(WicketFilter.java:479)

Exception [EclipseLink-7060] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.1.0.v20100614-r7608): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: Cannot acquire data source [java:comp/env/jdbc/myDs].
Internal Exception: javax.naming.NamingException: This context must be accessed throught a java: URL
at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException.cannotAcquireDataSource(ValidationException.java:464)
at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.JNDIConnector.connect(JNDIConnector.java:116)
at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.JNDIConnector.connect(JNDIConnector.java:94)
at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DatasourceLogin.connectToDatasource(DatasourceLogin.java:162)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.loginAndDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:579)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.login(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:228)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:380)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.getServerSession(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:157)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:214)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:202)
at de.company.myDs.controller.AbstractCrudController.getEntityManager(Unknown Source)
at de.company.myDs.controller.UserController.loadUserByName(Unknown Source)
at de.company.myDs.controller.LoginController.validateUserLogin(Unknown Source)
at de.company.myDs.pages.LoginPage$1.onSubmit(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.delegateSubmit(Form.java:1534)
at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.process(Form.java:934)
at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.onFormSubmitted(Form.java:896)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.invoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:182)
at org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.listener.ListenerInterfaceRequestTarget.processEvents(ListenerInterfaceRequestTarget.java:73)
at org.apache.wicket.request.AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.processEvents(AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.java:92)
at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.processEventsAndRespond(RequestCycle.java:1250)
at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.step(RequestCycle.java:1329)
at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.steps(RequestCycle.java:1428)
at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.request(RequestCycle.java:545)
at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doGet(WicketFilter.java:479)
```

web.xml

```
...
<resource-ref>
  <description>DB Connection</description>
  <res-ref-name>jdbc/myDs</res-ref-name>
  <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
  <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
...
```

context.xml

```
...
<Resource
    name="jdbc/myDs"
    auth="Container"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    maxActive="100"
    maxIdle="30"
    validationQuery="SELECT 1"
    testOnBorrow="true"
    testWhileIdle="true"
    timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="60000"
    minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="600000"
    username="root"
    password="passwd"
    maxWait="10000"
    driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
    url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/myDs" />
...
```

persistence.xml

```
...    
<persistence-unit name="myDs" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>

    <non-jta-data-source>java:comp/env/jdbc/myDs</non-jta-data-source>

    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>

    <class>de.company.myDS.model.User</class>

</persistence-unit>
...
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just add the class [`JPAEclipseLinkSessionCustomizer`](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Tomcat_Web_Tutorial#Session_Customizer) to your project and configure the persistence.xml as shown below:

```
<persistence-unit name="yourUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>

    <non-jta-data-source>java:comp/env/jdbc/yourDs</non-jta-data-source>        

    <properties>
        <property name="eclipselink.session.customizer" value="com.company.yourproject.yourpackage.JPAEclipseLinkSessionCustomizer"/>        
    </properties>

</persistence-unit>
```

You need this workaround only for Apache Tomcat.

Comment: Given link is not responding. I found a copy of the file in: http://code.google.com/p/buzzwords/source/browse/trunk/Buzzwords/maven/Buzzwords/src/main/java/com/buzzwords/utils/JPAEclipseLinkSessionCustomizer.java

Answer (score 1):

Set the datasource URL to "jdbc/myDs"
`<non-jta-data-source>jdbc/myDs</non-jta-data-source>`

Comment: This causes another exception:           javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name jdbc is not bound in this Context
     at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:770)
     at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:140)
     at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:121)
     at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:396)
     at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.JNDIConnector.connect(JNDIConnector.java:110)
     at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.JNDIConnector.connect(JNDIConnector.java:94)

Answer (score 1):

I hope you could solve the problem with the comments given ...

I fix it by adding a property "javax.persistence.nonJtaDataSource" with the same value as the element `non-jta-data-source`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to code a workaround for the `javax.naming.NamingException: This context must be accessed throught a java: URL` exception as detailed at http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Tomcat_Web_Tutorial#Session_Customizer

Also see this link which debugs through the problem

http://forums.java.net/jive/message.jspa?messageID=158622

Answer (score 0):

Year 2015 actualisation: I not sure Eclipselink SessionCustomizer is required. In my test all work without (Tomcat 7.x, Java 7.x, Eclipselink 2.4.x).

Some older materials suggest specific problem with Tomcat 5/6 and special way to resolve it.